# Replace a portion of a specific line

Tags: python

I do in python an history file, so that a user puts an URL and after that the program writes the URL in a txt file and on the same link the time that the user enter the website.

So my txt is like below:

```
- google.com 14:30
- yahoo.com 17:06
- apple.com 23:02
```

I want to create a function, so that the user put the url who wants to edit in parameter the time will be changed with the current time. The problem is that I do this function but when I see in the txt file I have something like this

```
google.com current_time 14:30
```

So I want to know who to delete the `14:30` from the txt file inplace.
Thanks you !

This is my function :

```
def Update(link):
    for line in fileinput.input("history.txt", inplace=True):
        localtime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
        print line.rstrip().replace(link, link+ localtime)
```

Comment: try `line.rstrip().replace(line, link+ localtime)` instead of `line.rstrip().replace(link, link+ localtime)`. Your code is only replacing the link part of the string instead of the entire line

Comment: I suggest using a database, a key-value store or the `shelve` module instead of a plain text file.

Comment: @UnholySheep : Your code not work

Answer (score 0):

If you copy the list without the last element will you get the correct answer?

```
def Update(link):
    for line in fileinput.input("history.txt", inplace=True):
        newline = line[:-1]
    return newline
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions.

```
import re

def Update(link):
    for line in fileinput.input("history.txt", inplace=True):
        localtime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
        print re.sub('\d{2}:\d{2}', localtime, line)
```

Comment: Your code replace all the time of all the links, and I want only the link in parameter